# isomorphism, integers of mod $n$.

Tags: ring-theory

Hello I think this is true, but I'm not sure.

---

**Setup:**

If $n = p_{1}\cdot p_{2} \cdots p_{n}$ where $p_{i}$ prime for all $i\in\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$.

Define the ring $A = p_{j}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

---

**Question:**
Is $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(n/p_{j})\mathbb{Z}$? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Does $\mathbb Z/(n/p_i)\mathbb Z$ have a multiplicative unit? Does $p_i\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Thanks! I think I confused group theory with ring theory. Thought there were only one ring of order 2 and thus $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ was the same as $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. But using the hint I obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Does it hold if all $p_{i}$'s are distinct? I.e $n$ square free?