# Isomorphism, integers mod n and the chinese remainder theorem

Tags: ring-theory

This is an extension of my previous question:

[isomorphism, integers of mod $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598713/isomorphism-integers-of-mod-n)

---

**Setup:**

If $n = p_{1}\cdot p_{2} \cdots p_{n}$ where $p_{i}$ *distinct primes* for all $i\in\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$.

Define the ring $A = a\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $a$ divides $n$.

---

**Question:**
Is $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(n/a)\mathbb{Z}$? And why?

---

**Attempt:**

I think it is true when the $p_{i}$'s are distinct. But I would like to get it verified. My argument/attempt is:

- We have $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p_{1}\mathbb{Z}\times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}/p_{n}\mathbb{Z}$ (chinese remainder theorem)
- Every ideal of a direct product $A\times B$ is of the form $J\times I$ where $J\leq A, I\leq B$ are ideals.
- An ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$  is of the form $a\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $a$ divides $n$

Using these three observations we can conclude that if $p$ divides $n$ then $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the original direct sum where we "delete" the summands corresponding to the prime divisiors not in $\dfrac{n}{p}$ and hence using the chinese remainder theorem (again) then $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/\frac{n}{p}\mathbb{Z}$.

Will this argument work? I know I skipped some details.

Comment: For $a=p_i$ it is exactly the old question, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598713/isomorphism-integers-of-mod-n.

Comment: In the old question we allowed $p_{i} = p_{j}$ for $i\neq j$. In this case/question $n$ is square-free.